# Why does python interpret my dictionary as a string?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

*Goal: I want to iterate over 'question1' + 'question2' as dictionaries, access their keys and print it's values, for example 'side_i_1' and 'side_n_1'*

'**questions**' is a dictionary with 2 keys ('question1', 'question2') - when I iterate over '**questions**' python prints the keys as strings (saying **TypeError: string indices must be integers** when I try to print a key value) - how do I access them as dictionaries and print their key-values?

attaching my dictionary:

```
{'avatar': 'man.png', 'friends': '2, 3, 4', 'questions': {'question1':
{'side_i_1': 'image1.png', 'side_i_2': 'image2.png', 'side_n_1': 'name1', 'side_n_2': 'name2'}, 
'question2': {'side_i_1': 'photo.png', 'side_i_2': 'photo.png', 'side_n_1': 'name3',
'side_n_2': 'name4'}}}
```

my code:

```
 result = requests.get('https://goat-aba06.firebaseio.com/' + str(self.my_friend_id) + '.json')
            data = json.loads(result.content.decode())
            questions = data['questions']
            for question in questions:
                print(question['side_i_1'])
                print(question['side_n_1'])
```

Thank you

Comment: Instead of `data = json.loads(result.content.decode())` have you tried `data = result.json`?

Comment: `for question in questions` iterates over keys, not values.

Comment: You probably want `for question_num, question in questions.items():`

Comment: Try printing `questions[question]['side_i_1']`

Comment: If your shown code throws an exception, please provide the entire traceback in the question (you can edit the question to add it). This helps a lot to better understand your question and you will get quicker/better answers.

Comment: @Asocia questions[question]['side_i_1'] 
worked perfectly! 
thank you everyone!

Comment: @syntonym noted, thank you!

Comment: Note that @Dan's suggestion would also work without changing anything else in your code and I think it's more *pythonic*.

Comment: @Asocia it actually didn't work - raised an error

Comment: @TomZiv What is the error? You should keep the body of your loop as in this question, and just change `for question in questions:` to `for question_num, question in questions.items():`

Comment: @Asocia thought you meant something else - works perfectly. Can you explain why please?

Comment: @TomZiv [Official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) can explain it better than me.